# how to upload plug-in in wordpress site (http://wordpress.org)

Tags: upload, wordpress

I have Created a plugin in word press.I wanted to upload it on official word press site in order to allow developers and other peoples to download that plugin.
The official site is word press is http://wordpress.org/

In short i wanted to upload my plugin to the following url

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

so that it can be listed as other plugins and visitors can download it .So how i can do this ?
please help

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/

Comment: Your question is not related to programming in any way. You may want to ask your question in the wordpress forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is place where you find 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add/

to submit your Plugin into http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ repository.

Regards,
[wordpress designer][2]